# Trying to figure out how to pass a "literal value of 20" in my code

Tags: c#

I'm working on a coding problem for school and I have pretty much everything complete, but I'm getting stuck on one problem that I haven't been able to find the answer for in the textbook or in other places online.

Part of the assignment is to "pass the total of the random values, the  average variable  by reference, and the literal value of 20"

I have this in my code currently:

```
CalcAvg(total, ref average, 20);
```

but the "20" is giving me an error.

Does anyone know the correct way to pass the literal value of 20 from Main to my CalcAvg method? For my CalcAvg method, I have this:

```
static void CalcAvg(double total, ref double average, 20)
```

And of course the "20" is giving an error there as well. I somehow need to pass the value of 20 from Main to CalcAvg, and I'm not sure how to do it without assigning the value to a variable, and I'm not sure that fits what is being asked.

Comment: That should be `static void CalcAvg(double total, ref double average, int numberName)` and the *calls* to CalcAvg should pass the literal 20

Comment: Thank you. I assumed from the wording that I needed to literally pass the number 20, but couldn't figure out how to do it. I'll have to assign it to a variable and then pass the variable.

Comment: No, you don't have to assign to a variable and pass the variable. `CalcAvg(total, ref average, 20)` is what you want to do. In that case you are passing the literal 20. If you assigned 20 to a variable and then passed the variable, then you are **not** passing the literal 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the function to expect the literal value and what the type is going to be.  Try this:

```
static void CalcAvg(double total, ref double average, int literal)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

And then you call it like you have been:

```
CalcAvg(total, ref average, 20);
```

Comment: It should be noted that `literal` there could be any other valid name